# How to process a CSV for exporting without displaying in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-csv

I had built a gridview to display the results from a query that is selecting teams from a various leagues. I could then choose to "download to CSV" by clicking on
a download to CSV button that appears when all the results are displayed in the gridview. This worked well. 
It was displaying this in a grid but when there were many teams being retrieved it was taking a while to load. Sometimes it would take so 
long it would start to the web page would hang. Now I want to bypass the displaying of the gridview and just be able to click the 
"download to CSV" button and for the results to be downloaded.
Presently, I have tried to comment out the code to display the Gridview but this
always seems to break the code. Alternatively I have tried to set the gridview to Visible="False" which does not allow the gridview to be shown,
but still processes the results (so still is subjected to the webpage hanging if the dataset in th gridview is beyond a certain size). Ideally
I want the griview to be bypassed completely but the results to be viewable in the CSV file.

Comment: That is C#, not VB.NET. and what error do you get? You didn't say what it was, and that is critical.

Comment: @mason - Sorry, I have changed it to C#, you are right. There is no error from this code, it works fine. I just want a way around it/commenting it out so that it still is able to produce the CSV file, but just won't display the gridview on the page (as I am having timeout issues with the large amount of rows that are being retrieved).

Comment: You mentioned you tried that and got an error. We need to see that code and error, not your working code.

Comment: When the code 'breaks' it does not give an error message as such, it just stops and then the "download to CSV" button does not appear. Unfortunately there is no actual error message. I guess what I am asking is what parts of the code can I comment out to make sure that it does not display the gridview but will allow the "download to CSV" button to work. I have been going backward and forward with this (commenting out and then uncommenting) trying to get it not to produce the gridview but allow for the download to CSV

Comment: @abitstuck you mean that while data coming from DB to be exproted to Excel directly ?

Comment: In future, please edit your question to make it clearer, rather than reposting it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060327/how-to-work-around-an-existing-gridview-and-send-the-results-straight-to-csv-for?noredirect=1. It is otherwise regarded as *noise*.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to download directly from `DB` here is an example :(As you didnt post any code i'm taking an example and explaining)

```
protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx");
                        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                            Response.Flush();
                            Response.End();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```